# Version Downgrade from laravel 6.11.0 to laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

`composer update` is throwing an error message while downgrading the Laravel version from 6.11.0 to 5.8. How to fix this issue? This is the screen shot:

[image: screen shot of error message]

Comment: Revert back these steps in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gs2wRTEAAFs

Comment: you have a permission error, so maybe try `sudo` before your command

Comment: Have you **read** that error message? Can you share the current `composer.json`?

Comment: @Nathanael I wouldn't recommend using `sudo`. See here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-untrusted-packages-safely.md

Answer (score 3):

Right at the bottom you'll see that it says:

> laravel/tinker v2.1.0 requires illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0 ...

Remember that every Composer package has a list of dependencies that it supports. This is to ensure that the packages you install can work correctly with each other.

Also, all of the packages that with `illuminute/` are Laravel-related packages and they should usually have the same version as the Laravel framework.

So that error message from above basically says that "Laravel tinker version 2.10.0 only supports Laravel versions that start with 6 or 7."

To find which versions of tinker supports Laravel 5.8, you can go to [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/tinker) and search for `laravel/tinker`. You can click on the different versions of tinker to see what versions of Laravel it requires under **Requires** (ignore the versions that end in "-dev" for now).

You'll see that the latest version of tinker that supports Laravel 5.8 is [v1.0.10](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/tinker#v1.0.10) (because it supports `illuminate/support: ~5.1|^6.0`) (you can read more about Composer and semantic versioning [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md)). **That means you need to set `laravel/tinker` to version `1.0.10` in your `Composer.json` file and then run `composer update`.**

Comment: Exactly !  Thanks for your help brother.

Answer (score 0):

Steps of downgrade:

1. make a backup from your project
2. edit your `composer.json` and make your `laravel` version `5.8`
3. run the command `composer update`

> When you do downgrade may stop of working or you use an option in new version of laravel that it isn't exists in the old version so you can check the upgrade [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade)